# Incorrect output for the second smallest integer

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, loops, integer

I'm having trouble finding the second smallest integer in my array. The array is unsorted (it's what's in the data.txt file), so I know that might be part of the problem, I'm not sure how to fix this in the simplest way. Afterwards I have to remove that integer from the array, move every number over and reprint the array, if anyone could help I'd really appreciate it.

```
const NUM = 10;

int Array[NUM];

ifstream infile;
infile.open("Data.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
{
    infile >> Array[i];
    cout << Array[i] << endl;
}

int Min = Array[0];
int Next = 0, SecondMin = 0;

for (int k = 0; k < NUM; k++)
{
    if (Min > Array[k])
        Min = Array[k];
}

for (int m = 2; m < NUM; m++)
{
    Next = Array[m];
    if (Next > Min)
    {
        SecondMin = Min;
        Min = Next;
    }
    else if (Next < SecondMin)
    {
        SecondMin = Next;
    }
}

cout << "The second smallest integer is: " << SecondMin << endl;
```

Comment: That part didn't cause an issue, everything was read into the array correctly, I just couldn't allow extra numbers past the NUM value in. There can only be 10 numbers in the array. So I can delete the .eof part and just keep the infile >> Array[i]. It works without that line.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to loop over the array twice to find the second smallest number. As long as you're keeping track of both the smallest and the second smallest, you should be able to find them both with a single loop.

There are a couple of other problems with this code:

Your check for end of file should probably be `if (!infile.eof())`

You don't need to check `if (i < NUM)` inside your loop. `i` will always be less than `NUM` due to the constraint on the loop.

If for some reason the number of items in the file is less than `NUM`, the rest of the items in the array will have undefined values. For instance, if there were only nine items in the file, after reading the file, `Array[9]` would have whatever value happened to be in that spot in memory when the array was created. This could cause problems with your algorithm.

I assume that this is some sort of homework problem, which is why the use of an array is required. But keep in mind for the future that you'd probably want to use a std::vector in this sort of situation. That way you could just keep reading numbers from the file and adding them to the vector until you reached the end, rather than having a fixed number of inputs, and all of the values in the vector would be valid.